# How to delete a running application in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to delete a running application from Windows. I killed all the processes with process name. While deleting immediately I got some error message. But after delaying task for 3 seconds, the application got deleted without any problems.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcessesByName(appName))
{
    process.Kill();
}

System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000 * 3).Wait(); // if we try to delete directly after killing process then error occurs
System.IO.Directory.Delete(sourceFolder, true);
```

Comment: Have you tried to wait for the process to exit? `Kill` isn't immediate (and is quite rude, so should be avoided - did you consider a more cooperative way of stopping the application?).

Comment: @luaan thanks for helping. I forgot to call `waitforExit`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is happening because this is how it was designed to behave:

From [`Process.Kill` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=netframework-4.8):

> **Note**
>
> The Kill method executes asynchronously. After calling the `Kill` method, call the [`WaitForExit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.8) method to wait for the process to exit, or check the [`HasExited`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.hasexited?view=netframework-4.8) property to determine if the process has exited.